# MPI_Recv/MPI_Send overhead

Tags: c++, mpi

I am working on a C++ application, where I use the MPI C bindings to send and receive data over a network. I understand that sending

```
const int VECTOR_SIZE = 1e6;
std::vector<int> vector(VECTOR_SIZE, 0.0);
```

via

```
// Version A
MPI_Send(const_cast<int *>(vector.data()), vector.size(), MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

is much more efficient than

```
// Version B
for (const auto &element : vector)
    MPI_Send(const_cast<int *>(&element), 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

due to the latency introduced by `MPI_Send`. However, if I want to send data structures which are not contiguous in memory (a `std::list<int>`, for instance), I cannot use version A but have to resort to version B or copy the list's content to a contiguous container (like `std::vector<int>`, for instance) first and use version A. Since I want to avoid an extra copy, I wonder if there are any options/other functions in MPI which allow for an efficient use of Version B (or at least a similar, loop-like construct) without incurring the latency each time `MPI_Send` is called?

Comment: You might look at Boost MPI, since it supports STL containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stepping and sending one by one through your `std::list` elements would indeed cause a significant communication overhead.

The [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) specification/library is designed to be language independent.  This is why it uses language agnostic [MPI datatypes](https://www.open-mpi.org/papers/workshop-2006/tue_05_datatypes.pdf).  And the consequence is that it can only send from contiguous buffers (which is a feature that most languages offers) and not from more complex data structures like lists.

To avoid the communication overhead of sending one by one, there are two alternatives:

- copy all the list elements into a `std::vector` and send the vector.  However this creates a memory overhed AND makes the sending completely sequential (and during that time some MPI nodes could be iddle).
- or iterate through your list, building smaller vectors/buffers and send these smaller chunks (eventually dispatching them to several destination nodes ?).  This approach has the benefit of making better use of [i/o latency and parallelism](http://www.bigdatanews.com/profiles/blogs/step-by-step-guidelines-to-optimize-big-data-transfers) through a ***pipelining effect***.  You have however to experiment a little bit to find the [optimal size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304249/is-there-an-optimal-byte-size-for-sending-data-over-a-network) of the intermediary chunks.